# How to set Muc Room Image Using XMPP in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, livechat

I am using XEP-0045 for room implementation in XMPP for iOS but it does not give any functionality regarding adding room Image.
Can any one suggest which protocol supports for setting room Image.

Answer (score 0):

XEP-0045 does not support avatar or image by default.

You will need customization. If you have provision to change the server you can follow user avatar [XEP-0153](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html). If not there is another work around (which is not so good). You can use the description field (muc#roomconfig_roomdesc) to store image data (should use base-64 encoded) along with your actual room description. But there could be limitation of description size at the server being used.